# Problem with adding a state to Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task

I just started learning how to use Task in C#. But I've encountered a problem in the very beginning. When I run this code , nothing gets displayed in Console window.Why?'

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task1 = new Task((obj) => PrintMsg(obj), "Hello Task");
    task1.Start();
}

static void PrintMsg(object msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your program is exiting before the task (which runs in a background thread) can finish.

Add `task1.Wait();` to wait for the task to finish running before finishing `Main()`.

Comment: do you need to add task1.Dispose(); after task1.Wait(); ?

Answer (score 3):

Add some code for wait the task:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task1 = new Task((obj) => PrintMsg(obj), "Hello Task");
    task1.Start();
    // or Console.ReadLine();
    task1.Wait();
}

static void PrintMsg(object msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg);
}
```